# Can't import package "No module named <modulename>"

Tags: python, module, flask

I am currently using Flask/Blueprint to make my simple app more modular.

My directories look like this:

```
Jobscraperapp/
    application.py
    modules/
        __init__.py
        jobscraper.py
```

In application.py:

```
from flask import Flask
import modules.jobscraper

app = Flask(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(jobscraper)
```

I exported the pythonpath for the modules package from the jobscraperapp directory with the following code:

```
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/modules"
```

but it always gives me an error that looks similar to:

```
No module named module
No module named module.jobscraper
```

etc.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding `/modules` to `PYTHONPATH`, which is the root level directory `modules`; I think you intended either:

```
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:./modules"
```

or

```
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:modules"
```

Alternatively, you can add the full path to `Jobscraperapp/modules`:

```
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/absolute/path/to/Jobscraperapp/modules"
```